# How would one go about generating a not-used post slug?

Tags: php

I have a website with a URL like: http://mysite.com/this-is-a-page and then I use that URL slug to get data from the database, however, if another page with the same exact slug exists, it will only display the one that resulted first and 9 times out of 10, it's not the correct one. I know I could just pass an ID to the slug, so the URL would be like: http://mysite.com/183/this-is-a-page but I know that there must be a way to loop trough the results before submitting a page and then adding a INT to end, "this-is-page1", "this-is-page2" and so on.

My question is, how do I loop trough it and generate a valid slug? By theory, I would do something like the following:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object(){
   if($post_slug === $row->post_slug){
       $post_slug = $post_slug + 1;
   }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure some of you know how to do this better and I'm all for learning the best practices. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Methinks the slug field should be `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really enforce a unique constraint on the data used as a URL slug. This way, you can warn users when adding new content when it isn't unique and they can adjust it as appropriate - or you could then append a time-stamp to ensure uniqueness.

You could run a clean-up script initially and then add a unique index if the data is in a database table.

Comment: Good point. I just thought that doing things without user knowing would be best, but obviously a user should have as much freedom as possible so simply not allowing to add new content if a query results in slug already existing and asking the user to change it would be better. I'm going to look into the UNIQUE thing, too. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I wrote a content management system, which just took whatever "title" the user entered and converted it into a slug. If there was an existing item with the same slug, it added a time-stamp to make it unique.